# How to add css to multiple classes

Tags: css, gravityforms

I have the following css which is working good. It applies to 4 different forms.

```css
    #gform_wrapper_1 .gform_body {padding: 25px; padding-left: 30px; box-shadow: 
    2px 2px 17px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);}
    #gform_wrapper_2 .gform_body {padding: 25px; padding-left: 30px; box-shadow: 
    2px 2px 17px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);}
    #gform_wrapper_3 .gform_body {padding: 25px; padding-left: 30px; box-shadow: 
    2px 2px 17px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);}
    #gform_wrapper_10 .gform_body {padding: 25px; padding-left: 30px; box-shadow: 
    2px 2px 17px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);}
```

Is there a way to put this all together in one css line of code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove all the id and get only one class like this: .gform_body {padding: 25px; padding-left: 30px; box-shadow: 
2px 2px 17px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use commas to separate the selectors:

```css
#gform_wrapper_1 .gform_body,
#gform_wrapper_2 .gform_body,
#gform_wrapper_3 .gform_body,
#gform_wrapper_10 .gform_body {
  padding: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 17px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
```

If you want this to apply to *all* forms, you could omit the IDs:

```css
.gform_body {
  padding: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 17px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
```

Comment: or remove all the id

Comment: I’m assuming the IDs are important, but if not, I agree that would be the preferred way of doing.

Comment: Yeah we don't have to much clue to know if it is important or not ;)

Comment: IDs are important of course, thanks for the quick solution!